# How to prove exponential function is inverse of logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I am try to prove that exponential function is inverse of logarithmic function using integral definition of natural logarithm function (method of my  interest)

And my approach is to find F(g(x))=x where F(x) is natural logarithm in integral form and g(x) is exponential function but after calculation I get

```
    F(g(x))=e^x-1
```

Is my approach correct ?
Or it is a calculation mistake ?
Any hint would be appreciated![image]!

Comment: Please, learn to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks for suggestion ,is it only reason to down vote ? No one can learn from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to show $\ln\exp x=x$ by showing both sides have derivative $1$; the agreement is trivial when $x=0$. For this you want a chain rule,$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{\exp x}\tfrac1tdt=\exp^\prime x\cdot\tfrac{1}{\exp x}=1.$$The error in your approach is using $x$ as both a free variable and a dummy variable. You should write $F(x)=\int_1^x\tfrac1tdt$ and $F(g(x))=\int_1^{e^x}\tfrac1tdt$. Since $t$ is neither $x$ nor $e^x$ as such but a dummy variable of integration, it doesn't get replaced by $e^t$ as in your logic.

Comment: Thanks for answer ,but as I mentioned I have taken logarithmic function as a integral from basic definition of natural logarithmic function (i.e area under curve 1/x from 1 to x and x>1) and then try to put x=exp x in that integral ,hope you'll understand my concern

Comment: @user215805 My calculation shows you how to differentiate $\int_1^{\exp x}\tfrac1tdt$. It may help if you edit your question to show how you got $\exp x-1$.

Comment: I edited it , where did I make mistake?

Comment: @user215805 See edit.